# SharePoint wsp solution: How to Deploy Globally

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, global, wsp, stsadm

I have created a wsp package and add it to

> Central Administration > Operations > Solution Management

using the `addsolution` command of stsadm. When I click on the Deploy Solution menu, it transfers me to deploy to the solution page. In this page, in the "Deploy To?" section, it shows me a dropdown list with entries like 'All Content web Applications'.

I want to deploy my solution globally so that it is applicable to all new web applications created after the deployment. I have seen WSPs for which "Deploy To?" section shows only a message like "This solution deploys globally" and no dropdown list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Globally deployed" only applies to WSP files that don't have web controls and web parts in them. These cannot be "Globally deployed", because the web.config of the web application you choose to deploy to is changed, i.e.  entries are inserted in order to register your .dll's containing web controls and web parts.

Comment: +1 "Globally deployed" is a WSP made up of a DLL only and no other artifacts.

Comment: When deployed to the global, do all web application pools recycle? @anchorpoint

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install it into the GAC - However here's a more informed answer:

> C:>stsadm.exe -o deploysolution -name
>   MossSolution.wsp -immediate
>   -allowgacdeployment
>
> this will deploy it globally. i will
>   check some time later for
>   allcontenturl. i have couple of batch
>   files to deploy WSP files at some
>   customers. i will check them to see
>   again in which scenario we used
>   allcontenturl. but my above reply
>   about not specifying a URL is correct
>   that in case when WSP contains only
>   dll for GAC, you should not specify a
>   URL.

from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0462dad3-1d56-4333-85a5-eafd1dd40980) on the social.msdn.microsoft.com forums